# How to come out of getRuntime.exec() when the executed process takes a long time to execute?

Tags: java, command-line, process

Inside Java program I am running the following?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp - src\ MyCode");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream));
```

The program MyCode is a java program.

Now, MyCode can get into situations like `infinite loop` or `long execution cycle`. At present, in such situations process p is waiting on MyCode 'forever'. What I need is, whenever MyCode execution is exceeding a certain amount of time, I want process p to end or get destroyed, so that I can continue with the next lines in the main program.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy() ?

Comment: I am familiar with the methods of process. But, I don't know how to write the timeout logic calling the destroy() method.

Comment: Look at my answer on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons exec contains an ExecuteWatchdog class https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog.html

```
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(30000);
Executer exec = new Executer(myloghandler, watchdog);
exec.setCommandLine(mycmdline);
int exitvalue = exec.execute();
if (Execute.isFailure(exitvalue) && watchdog.killedProcess()) {
    // it was killed on purpose by the watchdog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomment you to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
```

Then you can define StopProcess class:

```
class StopProcess implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some needed work
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
scheduler.schedule(new StopProcess(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```